# Why is document.getelementbyId not working in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firebug

I can't figure out why document.getElementById is not working in Firefox:

```
document.getElementById("main").style.width = "100";
```

When I check in Firebug it says:

TypeError: document.getElementById("main") is null

Does anybody know why this is happening?

EDIT: Unfortunately, the "body" element was a bad example. I changed it to another element with an id of "main".

Comment: sorry, bad example; i changed the question to an actual element with an ID.

Comment: Did you redefine document.getElementById somewhere or load some JS that does?  that works for me in firebug.

Comment: BTW: don't forget "px" when specifying the width, e.g. "100px"

Comment: What steve_c said. Give us a full failing case that we can reproduce. getElementById() works fine for all of us.

Comment: It turns out it wasn't working because I didn't include "px" - what Martin said.

Comment: Thanks everybody for all your help. Actually, you guys helped me fix two problems: "body" and "main".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set the id of the `<body>` element to "body":

```
<body id="body" ...>
```

Update:

Check if the following example works for you: http://jsbin.com/uyeca/edit
Click the Output tab to see the result (which should be a DIV with width 600px).

Comment: thanks, i just noticed that body was a bad example, and set it to a different id.

Answer (score 4):

put your script before

```
</body>
```

Or, if you use your script in `<head>` you may change code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //enter code here.
});
```

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementById

> Simply creating an element and
>   assigning an ID will not make the
>   element accessible by getElementById.
>   Instead one needs to insert the
>   element first into the document tree
>   with insertBefore or a similar method,
>   probably into a hidden div.
>
> ```
> var element = document.createElement("div");
> element.id = 'testqq';
> var el = document.getElementById('testqq'); //
> ```
>
> el will be null!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same prob...I was trying to use "getElementById" without the main structure of the HTML page-- tag was missing.

After adding  in my page it worked fine...I was working on a script that was supposed to be embeded on other sites--widget sort of thing.