# getElementById in Firefox

Tags: javascript

This below mentioned code works perfect in Internet Explorer but not in Firefox... I get an error in line in Firefox:

```
document.getElementById("supplier_no").value= values_array[0];
```

that `getElementById` returns `null`. how to solve the problem?

```
var winName;      //variable for the popup window
var g_return_destination = null ; //variable to track where the data gets sent back to.
```

Set the value in the original pages text box:

```
function f_set_home_value( as_Value ) {
  if (document.getElementById(g_return_destination[0]).name == "netbank_supplier_name_info" ) {
    //clear the old values
    for (selnum = 1; selnum <= 5; selnum++) {
      document.getElementById("expense_account"+selnum).value = "";
      document.getElementById("expense_account_name"+selnum).value = "";
      document.getElementById("expense_vat_flag"+selnum).value = "off";
      document.getElementById("expense_vat_flag"+selnum).checked = "";
      document.getElementById("expense_vat_amount"+selnum).value = "";
      document.getElementById("expense_vat_code"+selnum).value = "";
      document.getElementById("expense_period"+selnum).value = "";
      document.getElementById("expense_date"+selnum).value = "";
      if (selnum!=1) {//these are sometimes defaulted in, and in any case you will always have line1
        document.getElementById("expense_more_dept"+selnum).value = "";
        document.getElementById("expense_more_prj"+selnum).value = "";
        document.getElementById("expense_more_subj"+selnum).value = "";
      }
      document.getElementById("expense_amount"+selnum).value = "";
    }
    var values_array = as_Value[0].split("!");
    document.getElementById("supplier_no").value = values_array[0];
    document.getElementById("supplier_bankAccount_no").value = values_array[1];
    str = values_array[2] ;
    str = str.split(";sp;").join(" ");
    document.getElementById("default_expense_account").value = str;
    document.getElementById("expense_account1").value = str; 
    document.getElementById("expense_more_sok1").disabled = false; 
    str = values_array[3] ;
    str = str.split(";sp;").join(" ");
    document.getElementById("payment_term").value = str;
    strPeriod = calcPeriod(str,document.getElementById("due_date").value);
    document.getElementById("expense_period1").value = (strPeriod); 
    strExpenseDate = calcExpenseDate(str,document.getElementById("due_date").value);
    document.getElementById("expense_date1").value = (strExpenseDate); 
    str = values_array[4] ;
    str = str.split(";sp;").join(" ");
    document.getElementById("expense_account_name1").value = str;
    str = values_array[5] ;
    str = str.split(";sp;").join(" ");
    document.getElementById("expense_vat_code1").value = str;
    if (str == 0) { 
      document.getElementById("expense_vat_flag1").checked = '';
      document.getElementById("expense_vat_flag1").disabled = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("expense_vat_flag1").checked = 'yes';
      document.getElementById("expense_vat_flag1").value = 'on';
      document.getElementById("expense_vat_flag1").disabled = false;
    }
    str = values_array[6] ;
    str = str.split(";sp;").join(" ");
    document.getElementById("supplier_name").value = str;
    var str  = values_array[7];
    str = str.split(";sp;").join(" ");
    str = str.split("&cr;").join("\r");
    document.getElementById("netbank_supplier_name_info").value = str;
    strx = justNumberNF(document.getElementById("amount").value);
    document.all["expense_vat_amount1"].value = NetbankToDollarsAndCents(strx * (24/124)) ;
    document.getElementById("amount").value = NetbankToDollarsAndCents(strx);
    document.getElementById("expense_amount1").value = document.getElementById("amount").value;

    document.getElementById("expense_amount2").value = '';
    document.getElementById("expense_account2").value= '';
    //document.getElementById("expense_vat_flag2").value= '';
    document.getElementById("expense_vat_amount2").value= '';
    document.getElementById("expense_amount3").value = '';
    document.getElementById("expense_account3").value= '';
    //.getElementById("expense_vat_flag3").value= '';
    document.getElementById("expense_vat_amount3").value= '';
    document.getElementById("expense_amount4").value = '';
    document.getElementById("expense_account4").value= '';
    //document.getElementById("expense_vat_flag4").value= '';
    document.getElementById("expense_vat_amount4").value= '';
    document.getElementById("expense_amount5").value = '';
    document.getElementById("expense_account5").value= '';
    //document.getElementById("expense_vat_flag5").value= '';
    document.getElementById("expense_vat_amount5").value= '';
    str = values_array[8] ;
    str = str.split(";sp;").join(" ");
    if (str=="2"){
      document.frmName.ButtonSelPeriodisering1.disabled=false;
      document.frmName.ButtonSelPeriodisering1.click();
    }
    winName.close();
  }
}
```

Pass Data Back to the original window

```
function f_popup_return(as_Value) {
  var l_return = new Array(1);
  l_return[0] = as_Value;
 
  f_set_home_value(l_return);
}

function justNumberNF(val){
  val = (val==null) ? 0 : val;
  // check if a number, otherwise try taking out non-number characters.
  if (isNaN(val)) {
    var newVal = parseFloat(val.replace(/[^\d\.\-]/g, '.'));
    // check if still not a number. Might be undefined, '', etc., so just replace with 0.
    return (isNaN(newVal) ? 0 : newVal);
  }
  // return 0 in place of infinite numbers.
  else if (!isFinite(val)) { return 0; }

  return val;
};
function NetbankToDollarsAndCents(n) { 
  var s = "" + Math.round(n * 100) / 100  ;
  var i = s.indexOf('.') ;
  if (i < 0) {return s + ",00" } ;
  var t = s.substring(0, i + 1) + s.substring(i + 1, i + 3) ;
  if (i + 2 == s.length) {t += "0"} ;
  return t.replace('.',',') ;
}
```

Comment: I formatted your code, so it's at least a little easier to read now, but could you try coming up with a minimal test case?  In particular, I think having the document (HTML/XHTML) available will be necessary, since that's where the "elements" that `getElementById()` is looking for are defined.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML? Is there an element with an id of "supplier_no" on the page? That's `id`, not `name`; Internet Explorer may not care, but other browsers do.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473474/why-is-document-getelementbyid-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: *Of course* `document.getElementById()` works in Firefox. I suspect Syntactic has sussed out the problem for you, but as both he and Daniel say, without a look at your markup we can only guess. And, really, this is the sort of thing you should be able to debug with minimal effort.

Answer (score 2):

1) I'd really recommend using jQuery for this sort of thing. You're basically defaulting a large set of elements to empty string, and instead of having to write all that, you could give all your input elements a bogus class name (such as 'inputClass') and then write the following code in jQuery:

```
$('.inputClass').val('');
```

And have all your elements get updated, regardless of their id (in fact, you wouldn't even need one!). The code you currently have is nigh unreadable, and would be painful to maintain.

2) Firefox and IE have a known 'quirk' - if your names are the element's name attribute, and not the elements id attribute, then IE will find it just fine with a getElementById call, whereas Firefox will not. Check to make sure those names are actually the id attribute on your elements.

Answer (score 0):

I bring to you [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) this can save you A LOT, it could be just as simple as

```
$("#form .fieldsclass").val("");
```